# In Swift how do I configure a AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer?

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit, metal, modelio

For an iOS app I am converting some Objective-C code to Swift.

The Objective-C code uses a method with this signature:

```
+ (nullable NSArray<MTKMesh*>*)newMeshesFromAsset:(nonnull MDLAsset *)asset
       device:(nonnull id<MTLDevice>)device
 sourceMeshes:(NSArray<MDLMesh*>* __nullable * __nullable)sourceMeshes
        error:(NSError * __nullable * __nullable)error;
```

Here is how it is called:

```
NSArray<MTKMesh *> *mtkMeshes;
NSArray<MDLMesh *> *mdlMeshes;

mtkMeshes = [MTKMesh newMeshesFromAsset:asset
                                 device:_device
                           sourceMeshes:&mdlMeshes
                                  error:&error];
```

I am trying to convert this to Swift and I think I am doing it wrong because the method call always fails.

The Swift version of the above method:

```
open class func newMeshes(from asset: MDLAsset, device: MTLDevice, sourceMeshes: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray?>?) throws -> [MTKMesh]
```

How I use it:

```
do {

    var myPointer: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray?>? = nil
    myPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray?>.init(&modelIOMeshList)

    metalMeshList = try MTKMesh.newMeshes(from:asset, device:device, sourceMeshes: myPointer)

} catch {
    fatalError("Error: Can not create Metal mesh from Model I/O asset")
}
```

The method is supposed to populate the two array. It does not do that. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To a parameter of type

```
AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray?>?
```

you can pass the address of a `NSArray?` variable with `&`, so this should work:

```
var sourceMeshes: NSArray?
metalMeshList = try MTKMesh.newMeshes(from:asset, device:device,
                                      sourceMeshes: &sourceMeshes)
```